# pyagame.error: Video not intiialized. Code Posted

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Ask for any more information if needed!
I am using vscode's ide and python 3. When I run script.py the display will pop-up, but a half of a second later the display will disappear and will give this error pyagame.error: Video not intiialized.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
run = True

while run:
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])
  pygame.display.set_caption("TicTac")
  pygame.quit()
  x = 250
  y = 250
  width = 40
  height = 60
  vol = 5
  run = True
  while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
        run = False  
  run = False
pygame.QUIT()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do `pygame.quit()` immediately after `pygame.display.set_mode()`. `pygame.quit()` terminates all pygame modules. Remove it:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])
pygame.display.set_caption("TicTac")
# pygame.quit() <--- DELETE
```

`pygame.QUIT` is not a function, it is an enumerator constant. You can't invoke `pygame.QUIT`:

<s>`if event.type == pygame.QUIT():`</s>

```py
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

You need just one application loop, not 2 of them. Furthermore you have to update the window by either `pygame.display.flip()` or `pygame.display.update()`

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])
pygame.display.set_caption("TicTac")

x, y = 250, 250
width, height = 40, 60
vol = 5
run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # clear dispaly
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))  

    # draw the scene
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))

    # update display
    pygame.display.flip() 

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot more sense!